# Saving different models in ModelSerializer create not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a ModelSerializer for **Booking** model in its create method i have to update a field for **Room** model. But the **Room** model instance is not updated. Even though the **Booking** object is created

```
class BookingCreateUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Room.objects.all())
    booking_status = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=BookingStatus.choices())

    class Meta:
    model = Booking
    fields = [...
        ]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return BookingDetailSerializer(instance=instance,context=self.context).to_representation(instance)

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        room = validated_data['room']
        booking_status = validated_data.pop('booking_status')
        room.booking_status = booking_status
        room.save()
        validated_data['room'] = room
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

#### Expected Results

**Room.booking_status** should be set

#### Current Results

**Room.booking_status** is not set

## Fixed

I was testing the room in a `TestCase` where i had set it as `self.room = Room(...)`
I just needed to do `self.room.refresh_from_db()` before running the assertions

Comment: are you sure that the create method is getting called?

Comment: Yes brother i tested it in debug. The value is set and inside the function but after it finishes the Room object stays the same as before

Comment: is there any errors while processing the request?

Comment: nope. no errors. The Booking object is created but the room is not updated

Comment: Can you print `room` and show its output here?

Comment: room is Room object
At the start of create
{
'booking_status': '',
..}

After running room.save()
{
'booking_status': 'Reserved',
..}
After the create method ends
{
'booking_status': ''
..}

Comment: Thank you so much guys turned out i needed to run Room.refresh_from_db() before using it later.